# mysql でリモートからローカルに insert into select したい

Tags: mysql

mysql で、リモートサーバー上の mysql から select して、その結果をローカルの mysql に insert できたらいいなと思いました。

#### 質問

- insert into select 構文は、ホストが違う二つの mysql サーバーの間で実行できますか？

Comment: 私には実績がないのでコメントだけ残しますが federated ストレージエンジンを使えばできるような気がします。

Comment: データはそれぞれで保存しますか？それとも共有の一つですか？

Comment: @Daichi  テーブル単位でリモートのデータをローカルに持ってくる、が一番やりたいことではあります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

思っているものと同じかわかりませんが、"テーブル単位でリモートのデータをローカルに持ってくる"　ということはmysqldumpを使ってできそうです。

```
mysqldump -u username -p password -h remote_host --databases remote_database --tables remote_table --where="id=757575" | mysql local_database -u username -p password
```

こちらを[参考](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30586/how-to-insert-the-remote-table-data-into-another-table-in-my-local-computer-in-m)にしました。

Comment: 稼働中のデータベースからこれを行う場合、 --skip-lock-tables と --single-transaction が割と必須でした。